# pydrive authentication without local server - Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have the following `Python` code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
# Try to load saved client credentials
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
if gauth.credentials is None:
    # Authenticate if they're not there
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
elif gauth.access_token_expired:
    # Refresh them if expired
    gauth.Refresh()
else:
    # Initialize the saved creds
    gauth.Authorize()
# Save the current credentials to a file
gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

file1 = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'Hello3.txt'})
# Create GoogleDriveFile instance with title 'Hello.txt'
file1.SetContentString('Hello World!') # Set content of the file from given string
file1.Upload()

# Auto-iterate through all files that matches this query
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for file1 in file_list:
      print 'title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id'])
```

The format of `mycreds.txt` is:

```
client_id = "foobarbaz.apps.googleusercontent.com"
client_secret = "foobarbaz"
```

However, every time I execute that script, the local server still comes up for a manual authentication. My goal is to automate that part, so the user don't need to click in the authorization button.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

User consent is always required when authorizing access to Drive. Avoiding the authorization will void Google's security policies. More information is described here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization and here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-auth